# Python Create List incrementing words from sentence

Tags: python, list, iteration, combinations

If I took structured sentence like "do re mi fa sol" and broke it into words. How could I iterate in a way that would product a list containing the below?

Example:

```
           ['do', 're', 'mi', 'fa', 'sol'],
            do                  re              mi          fa      sol
            do re               re mi           mi fa       fa sol
            do re mi            re mi fa        mi fa sol
            do re mi fa         re mi fa sol
            do re mi fa sol
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what your intended output is. Do you want `['do','re','mi','fa','sol']` or `[ ['do','re','mi','fa','sol'], ['re','mi','fa','sol'], ['mi','fa','sol'], ['fa','sol'], ['sol'] (etc etc)]`

Answer (score 2):

To create all the sub-lists you want, try:

```
from itertools import chain, accumulate

def sublists(l):
    return chain.from_iterable(accumulate([s] for s in l[i:]) 
                               for i in range(len(l)))

output = list(sublists("do re mi fa sol".split()))
```

This gives me:

```
[['do'], ['do', 're'], ['do', 're', 'mi'], 
 ['do', 're', 'mi', 'fa'], ['do', 're', 'mi', 'fa', 'sol'], 
 ['re'], ['re', 'mi'], ['re', 'mi', 'fa'], ['re', 'mi', 'fa', 'sol'], 
 ['mi'], ['mi', 'fa'], ['mi', 'fa', 'sol'], 
 ['fa'], ['fa', 'sol'], ['sol']]
```

[Documentation for the `itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html). Note that `accumulate` was new in Python 3.2, but a Python implementation is included that you can use in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `split()` function. From [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> **str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])** - Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string...

**Code:**

```
a = "do re mi fa sol"
a_list = a.split()
print a_list
```

**Output:**

```
>>> ['do', 're', 'mi', 'fa', 'sol']
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use a set so you don't repeat.

```
txt = """do re mi fa sol do re re mi mi fa fa sol do re mi re mi fa mi fa sol do re mi fa re mi fa sol do re mi fa sol"""

a = set(txt.split()) #splits on whitespace then casts to a set
#a == {'mi', 'sol', 'fa', 'do', 're'}
```

If you need to preserve order, you can do:

```
a = [value for i,value in
    enumerate(txt.split()) if value not in txt.split()[i+1:]]
```

But that is much slower than using `set()`

Or maybe you're trying to combine your lists? Try:

```
txt = """do re mi fa sol do re re mi mi fa fa sol do re mi re mi fa mi fa sol do re mi fa re mi fa sol do re mi fa sol"""

a = set(txt.split())
b = [' '.join(list(a[i:])) for i in range(len(a)]
#b == ['mi sol fa do re', 'sol fa do re', 'fa do re', 'do re', 're']
```